# @within did not execute in spring-aop

Tags: spring, spring-aop

As per my understanding, `@within`  would execute if an annotation is at the class level so as per that understanding below snippet should run the `@within` block.

[example6](https://github.com/vihang16/AOPEXamples/tree/master/examples/M4-AOP/src/main/java/com/springaop/example6)

but my output did not print @within advice values. why?

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you. There are classes missing here. For questions needing many files, ideally just post a link to a GitHub project.

Comment: Only issue I am having with github that I need to recreate a new project, and push to my personal repo, that would be monitored in my org

Comment: That should not be any problem. I do not need your original, confidential code, but a minimal reproducer, as described in the MCVE article, which you do not seem to have read. You can rename and anonymise everything, as long as it reproduces the issue. I guess, your company will be happy that you are trying to solve the problem instead of wasting your work time being stuck.

Comment: @kriegaex added github link.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I was hoping for something including Maven or Gradle build configuration, because now I have to guess your Spring and dependency versions. I can take a look and will tell you, if I have any problems.

Comment: @kriegaex it has pom.xml here :https://github.com/vihang16/AOPEXamples/tree/master/examples/M4-AOP

Comment: Oh sorry, I was looking in the root directory. Great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main class only calls `testService.test`, but that method is not annotated by `@Log`. So why are you expecting it to be intercepted by the aspect? Also, there is only class `AnnotatedWithinTestImpl` in the `within` package, but you are not executing any code from it.

Adding

```java
AnnotatedWithinTestImpl annotatedWithinTest = (AnnotatedWithinTestImpl) context.getBean("annotatedWithinTest");
annotatedWithinTest.test();
```

to your main method should trigger the `testAllBeansWithAnnotation` advice and print:

```
WITHIN ANNOTATION LOG: CALL METHOD (...) within.AnnotatedWithinTestImpl#test with args []
```

For me, locally that works after adding the missing pieces of your code snippets.

---

**Update:** Thanks for the reproducer on GitHub. Now I can really reproduce and see what you did wrong. You use an `@Around` advice without calling `jp.proceed()`, i.e. the target method execution is blocked in the first advice. The second one therefore never fires. So

- either make sure that both advices proceed and return the proceed result,
- or, because you neither want to modify method parameters nor the method result, just switch from `@Around` to a simpler `@Before` or `@After` advice, then it works like a charm and there is no need to proceed or return anything.

This is all described in the Spring AOP manual.

The second option looks like this:

```java
    @Order(2)
    @Before("allBeans()")
    public void testAllBeans(JoinPoint jp) {
        LOGGER.setLevel(Level.FINEST);
        ConsoleHandler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
        consoleHandler.setLevel(Level.FINE); // set console handler logging level to FINE
        LOGGER.addHandler(consoleHandler);
        String type = jp.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName();
        String methodName = jp.getSignature().getName();
        Object[] methodArgs = jp.getArgs();
        print("WITHIN LOG: CALL METHOD " + type + "#" + methodName + " with args " + Arrays.toString(methodArgs));
    }

    @Order(1)
    @Before("allBeansWithAnnotation()")
    public void testAllBeansWithAnnotation(JoinPoint jp) {
        LOGGER.setLevel(Level.FINEST);
        ConsoleHandler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
        consoleHandler.setLevel(Level.FINE); // set console handler logging level to FINE
        LOGGER.addHandler(consoleHandler);
        String type = jp.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName();
        String methodName = jp.getSignature().getName();
        Object[] methodArgs = jp.getArgs();
        print("WITHIN ANNOTATION LOG: CALL METHOD " + type + "#" + methodName + " with args " + Arrays.toString(methodArgs));
    }
```

The console log then is:

```
WITHIN LOG: CALL METHOD com.springaop.example6.within.WithinTest#test with args []
WITHIN ANNOTATION LOG: CALL METHOD com.springaop.example6.within.WithinTest#test with args []
```

P.S.: Next time, please test your MCVE. You still had some old package names in your pointcuts, pointing to bogus packages.

Comment: I am getting only `WITHIN LOG: CALL METHOD` part, am not getting the annotation part log, seems it is an issue with 2 matching pointcuts, I updated my code with your snippet

Comment: Please note my updated answer explaining your mistake and suggesting two ways to fix it.

Comment: but by that logic, question I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75758765/spring-aop-proxy-call should have solved, but it didn't work there